# Did early latex paint contain lead?

Tags: painting, paint, lead, oil-based-paint

Recently purchased an 1890s cottage, and am doing some painting before moving in (the neon coloured kids rooms have to go lol). We know they went through lead abatement (remove and replace) for the windows in the early 2000s. However, some of the window sills, trim, and interior doors and trim in certain areas still look like they have might lead paint.

Bought a lead test which turned up nothing since the top layer is recent-ish latex, and was inconclusive in spots that were chipped, crackled or had a difference surface texture.

Did the rubbing alcohol test to see what was going on paint wise—and to see if I could get consistent results from the lead kit—and it seems to indicate latex at all exposed layers (color is lifting at all exposed layers) even those that seemed like they could be oil based/lead.

My current theory is that there is varnished wood under all the paint layers which is either causing the paint to look like it is lead or the lead paint was encapsulated at some point and that barrier is breaking down.

Questions:

- Did early latex paint contain lead?
- Could the rubbing alcohol test be giving inconclusive results?
- would an encapsulation coat for lead paint lift with alcohol? Or test negative/positive for lead?
- Is it okay to gently scuff/sand walls for painting as long as we don’t go below the current latex paint layer?

Many thanks for any insight!

Comment: If you're seriously concerned, get a professional lead test done by someone with proper equipment that can test all the layers of paint. The other option is to use a liquid stripper to completely remove the paint _without_ making dust that you might breathe in and/or spread around to kick up later. That will ensure that even if there is lead (the real issue is small children eating it, more than breathing it) you'll have it all gone.

Comment: Having lead paint on stuff is not an issue.  As @FreeMan says it is the eating of lead paint that is bad.  If young children are around then it is a worry and probably you will want it removed.  No kids or older(hopefully wiser) children should be safe to leave.